# GoPro (MP4) video timestamp sync with precision of milliseconds

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, ffprobe, gopro

I need your help with a data sync problem... I m currently trying to sync my GoPro video  with real world  time (a.k.a my notebook).  I manage to sync date and time of my notebook and my GoPro 3+ black  perfectly. The problem is that when the GoPro save the files in disk it round up the milliseconds on the creation_time (the milliseconds is always 000000) . Thus, turning the perfect sync impossible. In attachment is a picture of the meta information (extracted by ffprobe)  of the MP4 video.

My question is:  What I have to do, so the GoPro actually save the creation_time with precision of milliseconds?

Another small question: Looking at the attachment figure, we see the "timecode" which is a time synchronization data in the format of  hours:minuts:seconds:frame.  I was thinking that I could use the "frame" value to calculate the missing milliseconds value.   If we take this attachment, as a example, we can see that the frame value is  "36".  Meaning that the millisecond that it started to record was the one associated with the 36th frame of the FPS (in this video : 60fps) value:  Some thing like 1000/60 * 36  which is 600 milliseconds, thus the actual creation_time of this video would be : **2017-07-19T18:10:34.600**

Is this logic right? it didn't work !  I don't know what else to do.

P.S:  I need this kind of time precision because I will sync the video frames with a external sensor data that is recorded at 11hz.

Please Help

[image]

## update

I forgot to mention, even if you check the original raw file information, inside the GoPro SSD card, using "stats" to read the creation time (see attachment) it still has the same timestamp without milliseconds.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the file's creation time (not the metadata shown in ffprobe)?

Comment: @Mulvya Yes, I did. It  has the same timestamp "2017-07-19 18:10:34.000000000" .  I will update the question with this info, thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue? I am facing the same problem now.